# what does arrayListName.sort(null) do?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a project and the professor gave us some code. There is a line in the code that has me confused:

```
arrayListName.sort(null);
```

what does the call to `sort(null)` do exactly?

The doc says: "If the specified comparator is null then all elements in this list must implement the Comparable interface and the elements' natural ordering should be used. This list must be modifiable, but need not be resizable." What does it mean by the list's natural ordering? The elements we are trying to sort are phone numbers.

Note: I read the javadoc and it is not clear to me what it means. English is not my first language and the professor does not teach the class in English. I tried to google the question but am still confused as to what it means specifically.

Comment: `sort(null)` will likely throw a null pointer exception (did you read the docs?).  What that sort method should do is take a comparator which will be used in sorting the array list.

Comment: We need to know the type of `arrayListName` in order to answer this. Perhaps showing us some more of the code would help.

Comment: Assuming you know the type of `arrayListName`, which I would guess would be `ArrayList`, you should be able to search for the Javadocs for this method online.

Comment: the arrayList is supposed to be all of the elements from a union of sets from some files we have to read. He gave us some code and that is the first line of code for this part. I've seen null used with .add but never with .sort

Comment: @markspace the doc says: If the specified comparator is null then all elements in this list must implement the Comparable interface and the elements' natural ordering should be used. This list must be modifiable, but need not be resizable.    

What does it mean by the list's natural ordering? The elements we are trying to sort are phone numbers.

Comment: @new2code Update your question with that information. It shows your effort and that you tried thinking about the problem and it gives a very concrete question where you're stuck that people can answer. I'd change my downvote to an upvote once you've done that.

Comment: @MaxVollmer thank you for the suggestion. This is the first time I've posted a question so I'm not exactly sure what's the best way to get my message across.

Answer (score 6):

### Explanation

Supposed `arrayListName` is actually a variable of type `ArrayList`, then you are calling the `List#sort` method here. From its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-):

> `default void sort(Comparator<? super E> c)`
>
> Sorts this list according to the order induced by the specified `Comparator`.
>
> If the **specified comparator** is `null` then all elements in this list must implement the `Comparable` interface and the elements' **natural ordering** should be used.

So the method uses the **natural ordering** of elements when the comparator is `null`.

This natural ordering is given by a `compareTo` method on the items when they implement the interface `Compareable` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)). For `int` this sorts increasing. For `String` this sorts based on the [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Examples after sorting with natural ordering:

```
1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 8, 11

"A", "B", "H", "Helicopter", "Hello", "Tree"
```

Many classes implement this interface already. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). It counts `287` classes currently.

---

### Details

Let's compare that to the actual [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.sort%28java.util.Comparator%29):

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
    final int expectedModCount = modCount;
    Arrays.sort((E[]) elementData, 0, size, c);
    if (modCount != expectedModCount) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
    modCount++;
}
```

The comparator `c` is passed to the method `Arrays#sort`, let's take a look at an excerpt from its [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cjava.util.Comparator%29):

```
if (c == null) {
    sort(a, fromIndex, toIndex);
}
```

We follow that call to another `Arrays#sort` method ([implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29)). This method sorts elements based on their **natural ordering**. So no comparator is used.

Answer (score 2):

I typed it up and it did not throw an error. It actually sorted the list correctly. This is my code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
nums.add(2);
nums.add(4);
nums.add(3);
nums.add(1);

System.out.println(nums);

nums.sort(null);
System.out.println(nums);
```

The output was:

```
[2, 4, 3, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The sort method accepts a Comparator object, and if null is passed it defaults to natural ordering.

Comment: That's a bit...unexpected. You could get some subtle bugs with that.

Comment: Yeah, that's true

Comment: Why is that unexpected? The documentation clearly states that using `null` as comparator is allowed. The method then defaults to the natural ordering, if available.

Comment: @Zabuza because when dealing with `null` you usually get a `NullPointerException`. Defaulting to some functionality (which also requires that the elements implement `Comparable`) is not how the Java API usually works.

Comment: It really depends. I know some methods in the API that have optional parameters. Usually you can assign `null` to those to indicate that they should not be used. This method is one of them and the overloaded `sort` method (without comparator) just defaults to this by implementing it as `sort(null);`

Comment: @Zabuza I know some badly designed methods in the API too. Which is why it's odd to see it in a method introduced in `1.8`. I've been looking at the API for the past 20+ years too, so I kinda know what the general design guidelines are.

Comment: Well, if it's clearly documented, it's neither unexpected nor odd. It is just what it is...

Comment: Don't know if I would consider this as bad design. I mean sometimes you just have optional parameters. And `Optional` was not considered for this (only for optional return values). So `null` is a possibility to realized this. Another one is overloading, for example without exposing the helper method that takes `null`. Other than that, not much possibilities to realize optional arguments. But I agree that this can sometimes lead to confusion.